# How to get slugs from different models in the urls i.e path(<slug:slug1>/<slug:slug2>/)?

Tags: django, url, slug

Im trying to get a ur pattern that looks like this WWW.domain.com/slug1/slug2, where slug1 is the foreignkey to slug to. Think of it like library.com//. The author and book are two different models, both with their own slug. Is there a way where i can import the slug from author to the detailview of the book and then use it in the urls for the book detailview?

This is how i imagine the path to look like:

```
    path('brands/<slug:brand_slug>/<slug:model_slug>', views.Brand_ModelsDetailView.as_view(), name='model-detail'),
```

These are my models:

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, help_text='Enter the brand name',)  
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='brand_name', default = "slug_error", unique = True, always_update = True,)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a particular brand instance."""
        return reverse('brand-detail', kwargs={'slug':self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.brand_name

class Brand_Models(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    brand = models.ForeignKey('Brand', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', default = "slug_error_model", unique = True, always_update = True,)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a particular founder instance."""
        return reverse('model-detail', kwargs={'slug':self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My current attempt at the views:

```
class Brand_ModelsDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Brand_Models


    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(Brand_ModelsDetailView, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(
            brand__slug=self.kwargs['brand_slug'],
            slug=self.kwargs['model_slug']
        )
```

EDIT:

```
class RefrenceDetailView(generic.DetailView):
   model = Refrence

   def get_queryset(self):
       qs = super(RefrenceDetailView, self).get_queryset()
       return qs.filter(
            brand__slug=self.kwargs['brand_slug'],
            model__slug=self.kwargs['model_slug'],
        slug = self.kwargs['ref_slug']
    )
```

Comment: That code should work fine. What problem are you having?

Comment: This is the error i get :

    `NoReverseMatch at /catalog/audemars-piguet/`

`Reverse for 'model-detail' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'slug_error'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['catalog/(?P<brand_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P<model_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is just with the `get_absolute_url` method of Brand_Models; because the detail URL takes two slugs, you need pass them both to `reverse` there.

```
return reverse('model-detail', kwargs={'brand_slug': self.brand.slug, 'model_slug':self.slug})
```

Comment: Sure, as long as you update the URL pattern to match.

Comment: Wow Thank you! If I would like a third slug would this be right? `return reverse('model-detail', kwargs={'brand_slug': self.brand.slug, 'model_slug':self.slug})` with the view as in the edit?

Comment: I get this error: AttributeError at /catalog/rolex/submariner/
Generic detail view Brand_ModelsDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ah, you should override `get_object` rather than `get_queryset` for a DetailView. Remember to use `.get` rather than `.filter` there.

Comment: I cant thank you enough! I have been working on this for waay longer than i want to admit